# To have crashed VS to have crash

Tags: american-english, british-english, infinitive-clauses

Please check and let me know, if it is correct (to have crashed). It does not sound good to my ears but I am not a native English speaker. I have been learning English without learning grammar (as a native English speaker). Some times when I read which is not familiar to me, I ask questions here to clear my doubts.

**On Yahoo:**

> The Malaysia Airlines flight carrying 227 passengers and 12 crew went
>   missing in area near the South China Sea on Saturday as it flew from
>   Kuala Lumpur to Beijing and was presumed **to have crashed**.

Comment: FYI, "Sometimes when I read that which is not familiar to me" is correct, although very old-fashioned.  More modern usage would be "Sometimes when I read something that is not familiar to me" or simply "when I read something unfamiliar to me", where "something that is unfamiliar" is implied.

Answer (score 4):

One form of complement which *presume* licenses is an **infinitive** clause:

> English law presumes an accused person **to be** innocent until he is declared guilty by a jury of his peers.
>   Since you wrote this on company letterhead we presumed it **to reflect** company policy.

These are equivalent to the corresponding **finite clauses** headed by *that*:

> English law presumes **that** an accused person **is** innocent ...
>   ... we presumed **that** it **reflected** company policy.

When *presume* is passive, *BE presumed*, the subject of the main clause and an infinitive clause are the same. But with a finite clause, *presume* in the main clause requires a *dummy IT* for its subject:

> He **is presumed** to be innocent.
>   ***It* is presumed** that he is guilty.

Your example shows the construction with the infinitive **to have** + past participle which is equivalent to a finite clause with a perfect construction:

> The Malaysia Airlines flight ... was presumed **to have** crashed.
>   **=**
>   **It** was presumed that ... the Malaysia Airlines flight **had crashed**.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now and I also noticed that when I speak, I speak it in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

***to have crashed*** is a perfect infinitive phrase. Here it is used as the event has occurred recently and still has a bearing on the present or future.

*to have crash* won't look natural if *crash* is used as a verb there. If you want to have it as a noun, you need an indefinite article.

> *"....was presumed to have **a** crash."*

Answer (score 0):

This is a verb form which is called **Perfect Infinitive.**

Let's say there is a hunt for a criminal. In the news, you hear, "The robber is presumed **to be** hiding in the mountains." This is because we presume he is hiding there **now.**

But here, we are making assumptions about something that has happened **in the past.** We use the same phrase, and luckily, English has a special Infinitive that talks about the past—Perfect Infinitive. If we have not heard about the criminal for a while, and then an informant told the police that the criminal had left the country (but we can't confirm it definitely), we say that the criminal "is presumed **to have left** the country" (at the time when we are saying this, this supposed fleeing is already in the past.

So the sentence you've read was **not** a sentence about "having a crash" (where the verb would be **to have**, and then we use a noun). The whole three words "to have crashed" are one unit—a verb in an infinitive form. But in the past.